# When writing a proof, why do we want to assume a different but equivalent condition given in the proposition?

Tags: proof-writing

[image]

In the proof for the inductive step, we start by assuming $k \ge 10$. But along the way, the author mentions $k \ge 1$ and $k \ge 7$ to justify the inequality.

Why do we bother to do this instead of just sticking with $k \ge 10$?

Comment: @G.Bach I don't think this is a duplicate as although the image is the same, the question asked is targeted at a different aspect of the solution.

Comment: You should edit your other question instead of making a new one for any new aspects you'd like to ask about.

Comment: Okay. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in those cases all that was needed was to show that $k\geq1$ or $k\geq7$, which is obviously true if $k\geq10$. The author was simply stating the minimum required for the inequality to be true at each stage.

Comment: Giving exact limits is a way to evidence having thought about the other conditions, I guess